# Calculate item count and return as column

Tags: sql-server

I've a sql server 2014 table named `Machines` with this items

```
ID  || ProjectName       || MachineTypeID              || MachineName
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   || project1          ||           1                || m1
1   || project2          ||           2                || m2
1   || project1          ||           2                || m3
1   || project2          ||           1                || m4
1   || project1          ||           2                || m5
```

And another table named `MachineTypes` with this items

```
Id || Title 
-------------------
1  || BigMachine
2  || SmallMachine
```

All wanted to write a query with this output

```
ProjectName || BigMachineCount       || SmallMachineCount
----------------------------------------------------------
Project1    ||          1            ||        2
Project2    ||          1            ||        1
```

I hope it is possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Where did i do wrong?

Comment: It's not about wrong anything but we need sample data, your efforts and expected and current output to move on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT (after you posted example)

This query should give you the result you want. I'm pretty sure this solution to your problem is already somewhere here @ SO.

Link to sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3ef7a/1

```
select ProjectName, 
       sum(case when MachineTypeID=1 then 1 else 0 end) as BigCount, 
       sum(case when MachineTypeID=2 then 1 else 0 end) as SmallCount
from Machines group by ProjectName
```

Comment: Thanks, and by adding Group by ProjectName it returns all i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
declare @t1 table(ID int, ProjectName varchar(10), MachineTypeID int, MachineName varchar(5));
insert into @t1 values
(1, 'project1',1, 'm1'),
(1, 'project2',2, 'm2'),
(1, 'project1',2, 'm3'),
(1, 'project2',1, 'm4'),
(1, 'project1',2, 'm5');

declare @t2 table (Id int, Title varchar(20));
insert into @t2 values
(1, 'BigMachine'),
(2, 'SmallMachine');

select ProjectName,
       max(case when MachineTypeId = 1 then cnt end) BigMachineCount,
       max(case when MachineTypeId = 2 then cnt end) SmallMachineCount
from (
    select ProjectName, MachineTypeId, count(*) cnt from @t1
    group by ProjectName, MachineTypeId
) a group by ProjectName
```